# Compute the likelihood from pdf : $L= \prod^{n}_{i} p(x_{i})$

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I would like to use the product value in order to derive the likelihood. Say we have a Gaussian pdf $p(x_{i})$ for $\{i\}_{i=1}^{n}$ and define the likelihood as $L= \prod^{n}_{i} p(x_{i})$.

**Example 1:**

```
Likelihood[
 NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], {Table[Subscript[x, 
   i], {i, n}]}]
```

**Example 2:**

```
Product[PDF[NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]], {x}], {1, n}]
```

[image]

***Normal distribution example:***

[image]

***Uniform example:***

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
**EDIT 2:** Modified for unspecified dimension

Clear["Global`*"]

$Assumptions = Element[x, Vectors[n]];

likelihood[dist_, x_] :=
 Module[{n = TensorDimensions[x][[1]], 
  dom = DistributionDomain[dist]},
  Assuming[DistributionParameterAssumptions[dist],
   ExpandAll[
     PowerExpand[
       E^Sum[Log[
          Simplify[PDF[dist, x[k]],
           dom[[1, 1]] <= x[k] <= dom[[1, 2]]]],
         {k, 1, n}]] /.
      Sum[const_?(FreeQ[#, k] &) + rest_, {k, 1, n}] :> 
       n*const + Sum[rest, {k, 1, n}]] //. 
        E^(t1_ + t2_) :> E^t1 * E^t2]]
```

Examples

```
likelihood[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], x]
```

[image]

```
likelihood[UniformDistribution[{a, b}], x]

(* (-a + b)^-n *)
```

Comment: Hi @BobHanlon , i am trying to get to something like the likelihood expression I just added.